# HTML 5 Currency format

Tags: javascript, html

I am using lots of HTML 5 input controls in my pages. One of my requirement is to have a textbox with currency feature. For this i tried this:

```
<input type="number" pattern="(d{3})([.])(d{2})" />
```

This allows me to type values like 10,000.00

But still all its not meeting all my requirements. I want that if the user types in 10000
 it should convert it to currency format like 10,000 onblur.

And when i read the value from the input type in my Javascript, it should give me a float instead of a string value which i cannot use to calculate without parsing.

Comment: `input type="number".value` will be a string in any case. You need to parse it at some point anyway...

Comment: input type="number".value will be string in any case. but simple having parseFloat(input type="number".value) would have worked in all cases.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a workaround with an additional `input type="text"`:

http://jsfiddle.net/UEVv6/2/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="userinput" pattern="[0-9]*">
<br>
<input type="number" id="number">
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("userinput").onblur =function (){    

    //number-format the user input
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""))
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .toString()
                    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

    //set the numeric value to a number input
    document.getElementById("number").value = this.value.replace(/,/g, "")

}
```

regex is from here [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem coupled with the Amith solution below this.

Answer (score 2):

try this - http://jsbin.com/azOSayA/1/edit

```
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return val;
  }
$('#elementID').focusout(function(){

  alert(commaSeparateNumber($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Amith. You solved my problem.